# Pandas: How to change titles of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am creating a numpy matrix (2 columns, each 10 elements).
After conversion to a Pandas Dataframe I want to change the names of the columns from 0->x and 1->y.
How is the solution for this?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = np.arange(10)
y = x**2

# create numpy matrix of (2 x 10) 
matrix = np.stack((x, y), axis=-1)

#conversion to Pandas
df = pd.DataFrame(matrix)

print(df)

    0   1
0   0   0
1   1   1
2   2   4
3   3   9
4   4   16
5   5   25
6   6   36
7   7   49
8   8   64
9   9   81
```

Comment: Use the `columns` parameter?

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(matrix, columns=[...])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `columns` parameter of `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(matrix, columns=['x', 'y'])
print(df)

# Output
   x   y
0  0   0
1  1   1
2  2   4
3  3   9
4  4  16
5  5  25
6  6  36
7  7  49
8  8  64
9  9  81
```

Comment: @BigBen, I created a community wiki...

Comment: Your effort is valiant, but IMO not worth your much more valuable time. Who cares about rep points? I think it's more important that SO not get bogged down with low-quality, little-to-no-use questions. There are only so many people in the world who will continue to answer them. There are many many more people who will continue to ask them, unless we push back.

Comment: Since @BigBen is unhappy, should I delete my question?

Comment: @len that is your decision to make, not mine to influence. A better idea going foward is to do lots of research, like *way* more than you think you should, before asking a question. If you're having a simple issue, it's very likely you're not the first. And it's also likely that the docs answer it.

Comment: ok you convinced me, then lets delete it ... sorry @Corralien

Comment: Don't be. You have your answer and this is the most important for me!

Comment: Then I leave it.

Comment: I created a [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740) so no one earns points.